# flutter painting on canvas and erase drawing

Tags: flutter, canvas, drawing, eraser

i am working on a canvas drawing module in to it i need to erase user drawing

basic funda is

1. adding image in canvas
2. user can draw on image using pencil (i.e black color) now user can erase this black color on erase function (i.e clear user drawing )

my try is :

```
case PaintMode.eraser:
              print('eraser**** _image Painter!!!*'); // print(_painter.color)
              //  canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());1
              var _painterTemp = _painter!
                // ..color = Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0.8)//also tried it
                ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear;
    
              for (var i = 0; i < _offset!.length - 1; i++) {
                if (_offset[i] != null && _offset[i + 1] != null) {
                  final _path = Path()
                    ..moveTo(_offset[i]!.dx, _offset[i]!.dy)
                    ..lineTo(_offset[i + 1]!.dx, _offset[i + 1]!.dy);
                
                } else if (_offset[i] != null && _offset[i + 1] == null) {
                 
                  canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [_offset[i]!], _painterTemp);
                }
              }
              //   canvas.restore();//1
    
              break
```

but i am getting black lines only

took reference from
https://github.com/yellowQ-software/yellowQ-Flutter-Image-Painter

edit-----
i've edited like

```
case PaintMode.eraser:
          print('eraser**** _image Painter!!!*');

       
          var _painterTemp = _painter!
            ..color = Colors.transparent
            ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear; //srcOver

          for (var i = 0; i < _offset!.length - 1; i++) {
            if (_offset[i] != null && _offset[i + 1] != null) {
              final _path = Path()
                ..moveTo(_offset[i]!.dx, _offset[i]!.dy)
                ..lineTo(_offset[i + 1]!.dx, _offset[i + 1]!.dy);

              canvas.drawPath(_path, _painter);

              canvas.drawPath(_path, _painterTemp);
              canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());
            } else if (_offset[i] != null && _offset[i + 1] == null) {
              canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [_offset[i]!], _painter);
              canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [_offset[i]!], _painterTemp);
            }
            //  canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint()); //1
          }
          //   canvas.restore();//1

          break;
```

but not working but getting `custom painter called canvas.save() or canvas.saveLayer() at least 773 more times than it called canvas.restore().`

any help?

Comment: Can't you use the color of the background (canvas), so it looks like it is erasing?

Comment: @jigar 1. adding image in canvas 2. user can draw on image using pencil (i.e black color) now user can erase this black color on erase function (i.e clear user drawing )

Comment: oh okay, I see.

Comment: yes, you need `saveLayer` - first you have to draw black lines, then lines with `BlendMode.clear`

Comment: @pskink can you please explain in some more details?

Comment: you call `canvas.drawImage`, then `canvas.saveLayer`  then you draw all the lines with `paint.color = Colors.black`, then all the lines with `paint.blendMode = BlendMode.clear` - and finally `canvas.restore`

Comment: @pskink please check update.its not working but getting issue.correct me where i am wrong

Comment: `canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, Paint());
canvas.saveLayer(Offset.zero & size, Paint());
final paint = Paint();
canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(100, 100, 200, 200), paint..color = Colors.black);
canvas.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(150, 150, 100, 100), paint..blendMode = BlendMode.clear);
canvas.restore();` - run it as it is and then run it again without `canvas.saveLayer` and `canvas.restore`

Comment: @pskink not working

Comment: @Developer did you solve this? i need to erase the drawing on my image